# ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in asp.net core application deployed in digitalocean droplet in dockerized environment

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, https, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean

I am using Digital Ocean droplets for hosting my asp.net core application.

In docker-compose file  I set this configuration:

```
 environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=***************
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/dev_cert.pfx
    volumes:
      - ./******/https/:/https/
```

In the digital Ocean panel I create a new Certificate using Let’s Encrypt as they mention in their documentation. I checked also if my droplet is listening on port 443

```
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      18481/docker-proxy
```

The problem is I got always this warning **NET:: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID** in the browser

Does anyone Know How to fix this problem please?

Thanks